# Select all rows where there is not a specific value in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

This is a wordpress installation, but I think the question is more of a general sql question.  First off, my sql skills are not great (I don't even know if I'm following the correct format for illustrating the db).

I've got two tables:

```
wp_posts :

    ID (pk)  |   post_name  |  ...
----------------------------
    45       |    "Hello"
    91       |    "Funny"
    16       |    "Wheat"

wp_postmeta :

    post_id (fk)  |    meta_key      |   meta_value  | ...
------------------------------------------------
    45            |    "_edit_lock"  |   5789789834
    45            |    "fizzbizz"    |   "foobar"
    91            |    "_something"  |   "teve"
```

I would like to select all rows in wp_posts where there is NO corresponding row in wp_postmeta where meta_key = "fizzbizz"

I originally had this query, but someone pointed out that it would not retrieve ID = '16' in the above case. How would I correctly write the query?

```
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM wp_posts p 
    JOIN wp_postmeta m 
    ON p.ID = m.post_id 
    WHERE m.meta_key <> 'fizzbizz' 
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC;
");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your current query with the following changes:

`LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`

add

`OR m.metakey IS NULL` to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m 
    ON p.ID = m.post_id 
    WHERE m.meta_key <> 'fizzbizz'
       OR m.metakey IS NULL
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC;
```

Comment: @JMC Creative - it will still work since you have a row that meets the criteria.  Even though you do have one row that has `'fizzbizz'` you have another that doesn't and that row will be in your record set.  Do you want it to be?

Comment: @JMC Creative - also with your edit your originally query would work, but you should still use the edited version to account for records with no row in the meta table

Comment: @JNK, I don't want to ask for too much here, but can you explain _why_ I should use `LEFT JOIN` ? I thought that means "only retrieve the data in the LEFT table".

Comment: @JMC Creative - `LEFT JOIN` means "Get everything from the LEFT (first) table regardless of whether the JOIN condition is met".  If you use a `LEFT JOIN` and a `WHERE` condition on the right table's join key being `NULL`, you are asking for all rows in the left table that don't have a corresponding record in the right table.

Comment: +1 for the extra information, but I'm going to accept @Andy Paton's answer, because it's exactly the same and he hit "submit" first (and he's only got 131 rep). Thank you very much though!

Comment: @JMC Creative - OK, but in fact he answered a couple minutes after I did :)

Comment: @JNK - you did indeed, im slower on the old typing than you. I don't mind not getting the Rep... fair is fair

Comment: @JNK I see "22 mins" on his answer and "24 mins" on yours. ?

Comment: @JMC Creative - Yeah, 24 minutes ago is earlier than 22 minutes ago :)

Comment: @JMC - no worries, it's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m 
ON p.ID = m.post_id 
WHERE m.meta_key <> 'fizzbizz'
OR m.metakey IS NULL
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC;
```

Should do the trick ;-)